# Java Weka - Cannot create a new output file. Standard out is used

Tags: java, csv, weka

I have a Java program that converts CSV files to Weka's ARFF format.

It works perfectly the first time it's run in any given session, however it subsequently always fails with the message:

> Cannot create a new output file. Standard out is used.

Here's the program:

```
import java.io.File;
import weka.core.Instances;
import weka.core.converters.ArffSaver;
import weka.core.converters.CSVLoader;

public class CSV2Arff {
      /**
   * takes 2 arguments:
   * - CSV input file
   * - ARFF output file
     * @param args
     * @throws java.lang.Exception
   */
  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    if (args.length != 2) {
      System.out.println("\nUsage: CSV2Arff <input.csv> <output.arff>\n");
      System.exit(1);
    }

    // load CSV
    CSVLoader loader = new CSVLoader();
    loader.setSource(new File(args[0]));
    Instances data = loader.getDataSet();

    // save ARFF
    ArffSaver saver = new ArffSaver();
    saver.setInstances(data);
    saver.setFile(new File(args[1]));
    //saver.setDestination(new File(args[1]));
    saver.writeBatch();
  }
}
```

Full error from console:

> ```
> Oct 31, 2016 3:53:39 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
> INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
> Oct 31, 2016 3:53:39 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
> INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
> Oct 31, 2016 3:53:39 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
> INFO: Server startup in 6142 ms
> Cannot create a new output file. Standard out is used.
> ```

Comment: can you show all the stacktrace?

Comment: Are you calling programm always with same destination fileName?

Comment: @Kacper Yes, it should overwrite the file.

Comment: @davidxxx Sure, I will add that now

Comment: And in server logs (TOMCAT_HOME/logs) , you have not more details ?

Comment: @davidxxx Sure. There's more but it's just stuff that I know for sure is unrelated because I've seen the other messages over and over for months, unrelated to this issue. Here's the full log: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/8c3ffedc8d6ceca65cbd8ba5552c14e2

Comment: "SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation" means logs are disabled. You should configure conveniently SLF4J to enable logs and have debugging information when an exception occurs

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [weka mail list](https://list.waikato.ac.nz/pipermail/wekalist/2011-January/050901.html), this error is a file issue. Other emails suggest to use [Java I/O approch](https://weka.wikispaces.com/Save+Instances+to+an+ARFF+File) to save arff file.

> ```
> This error is coming from the CSVSaver and indicates that it is unable 
> to create the directory and/or file that you've specified. More than 
> likely it is something to do with permissions on where it is trying to 
> write to.
> ```

Try following code.

```
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.File;
import weka.core.Instances;
import weka.core.converters.ArffSaver;
import weka.core.converters.CSVLoader;

public class CSV2Arff {
      /**
   * takes 2 arguments:
   * - CSV input file
   * - ARFF output file
     * @param args
     * @throws java.lang.Exception
   */
  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    if (args.length != 2) {
      System.out.println("\nUsage: CSV2Arff <input.csv> <output.arff>\n");
      System.exit(1);
    }

    // load CSV
    CSVLoader loader = new CSVLoader();
    loader.setSource(new File(args[0]));
    Instances data = loader.getDataSet();
    String fileName = args[1];


    // save ARFF
    BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(fileName));
    writer.write(data.toString());
    writer.flush();
    writer.close();

  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think `ArffSaver` is going to override the file. If you want to overwrite it please delete file if exist before seting is as a target. If you want concatenate data please try `writeIncremental`

You have:

```
saver.setFile(new File(args[1]));
```

I'd go with something like:

```
File f = new File(args[1]);
if(f.exists()) { 
    f.delete();
};
saver.setFile(new File(args[1]);
```

Comment: It makes total sense to me, but it actually still throws the same error, "Cannot create a new output file. Standard out is used." . I tried cleaning the working directory, refreshing the project, and restarting Tomcat.

Comment: @Hack-R Can you try save to multiple files. Just to confirm the problem is with using single file? `int i = (int) Math.ceil(Math.random() * 10000); saver.setFile(new File(args[1] + i)); `

Comment: @Hack-R I've also slightly changed the code in my answer. If you will be able to write to multiple files it means problem is with reusing file. If you get error also with additional digits in filename it means my idea is wrong.

Comment: Thanks. I am at home now so I will have to wait until tomorrow to try it but I will go ahead and upvote your answer. Cheers.